# Datatable function on page 2 pagination doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

Good day! I'm using datatable that shows a list for students and active and deactive as a hyperlink.

It works on page 1 but on page 2 or when I search the data my function which is the active and deactive doesn't work..

[image: This is my data]

This my codes to deaactive an active acccount:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <?php if($row->Status=='Active') echo '<a href="#deactive_account" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row->Student_ID.' class="activate" style="color:green;">Active</a>'; ?>
    <?php if($row->Status=='Inactive') echo '<a href="#active_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row->Student_ID.' class="activate" style="color:red;">Inactive</a>'; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Post output of `print_r($row);`.

Comment: Active stdClass Object ( [Student_ID] => 2009018262 [Password] => 2009018262 [Lastname] => Rene Lynne [Firstname] => Borja [Middlename] => C. [Status] => Active )

Comment: Update the question by posting full code for the page. Although, I don't think this is a problem, but both your links have same class `activate`, shouldn't be one `deactivate`?